# code with cv2 library doesn't work what's wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

This code generates an error:

```
import cv2
import face_recognition as fr
while 5<6:
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imwrite('camera1.jpg', frame)
    cap.release()
    img = cv2.imread("CHEL.jpg")
    rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_en = fr.face_encodings(rgb_img)[0]

    img1 = cv2.imread("camera1.jpg")
    rgb_img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_en1 = fr.face_encodings(rgb_img1)[0]

    result = fr.compare_faces([img_en], img_en1)
    if result == True:
        print("А я тебя узнал!")
    else:
        print("Чё то не так")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\cvcvcvcv2\ky.py", line 12, in <module>
    img_en = fr.face_encodings(rgb_img)[0]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 214, in face_encodings       
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 214, in <listcomp>
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], face: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
    2. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
    3. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], faces: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors      
    4. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], batch_faces: List[_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections], num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectorss
    5. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors

Invoked with: <_dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1 object at 0x00000141E21244F0>, array([[251, 252, 253, ...,  88,  90,  91],
       [251, 252, 253, ...,  88,  89,  90],
       [251, 252, 253, ...,  88,  88,  88],
       ...,
       [221, 221, 222, ...,  51,  49,  47],
       [223, 223, 224, ...,  49,  47,  48],
       [224, 224, 225, ...,  48,  46,  50]], dtype=uint8), <_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection object at 0x00000141E20FC8B0>, 1
```

Comment: I have all the photos and the photos from the camera are also saved in the same .jpg format.

Comment: Move cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0) before while-else block. 

    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0
    while cap.isOpened() and 5<6:

Comment: no, that's the mistake:
Invoked with: <_dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1 object at 0x000002003BEB3EB0>, array([[251, 252, 253, ...,  88,  90,  91],
       [251, 252, 253, ...,  88,  89,  90],
       [251, 252, 253, ...,  88,  88,  88],
       ...,
       [221, 221, 222, ...,  51,  49,  47],
       [223, 223, 224, ...,  49,  47,  48],
       [224, 224, 225, ...,  48,  46,  50]], dtype=uint8), <_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection object at 0x000002003B3BE4B0>, 1